# GAE and Google API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build a GAE application that shell use GCM API.
(I am working with Eclipse Juno, having GWT, ADT installed).
I am using Google's python example, and I can't make it work, I'd be really grateful 
if you could advise me where am I loosing my way.
First it's probably important to note that I have created a project in the Console, activated 
the API, and got my project whitelisted by Google. So far so good?
I have created a python GAE project, based on Google's example in the following link -

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html

At this point I face the following difficulty - 
client = xmpp.Client('gcm.googleapis.com', debug=['socket'])
The Client class is not recognized by the pre-interpreter. When I check in the XMPP package,
it looks though this class actually doesn't exist there... - how to handle this one?

I've tried to add the GCM APIs to the project, thinking that this might be the problem, 
but the G->Add Google APIs...->Selection proposes all APIs but GCM.

My next step was to try installing google-api-python-client-gae-1.2.
I've found the following guide -

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started#simple

I've installed the lib, and then paid attention to the fact that in GAE, all source should be present in the project lib - so I have manually copied "apiclient" lib's content to my src lib.
Nevertheless, for the following line I've added from Google's example -

service = build('my_service', 'v1', developerKey=api_key)

when I run the GCC application, the following error occurs:

from apiclient.discovery import build
ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery

I'm struggling through those issues quite a while, please help...

Comment: What xmpp library are you using? Not that the Python example on the page you've linked to doesn't seem to be meant for GAE, it doesn't use any of the libraries from there.

Comment: I've tried using the xmpp library given by google.appengine.api import xmpp. (at some point I've linked Jabber xmpp I've downloaded, but it lacks the specific API required to connect to Google API, so I left this direction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mostly headed in the wrong direction.

App Engine's XMPP API lets you send and respond to XMPP messages.  See the docs:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/
There's no "Client" class.  You have to code against the API provided by the XMPP service.

You're better off just using the HTTP connection server instead of XMPP.  It's more straightfoward:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

Comment: First, thanks. In http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html they suggest a python example where the line                                 client = xmpp.Client('gcm.googleapis.com', debug=['socket']) is present. I have deployed that example, but there is no Client in google.appengine.api - xmpp. In addition, in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/ they do not descrobe how to connect to the Google API's GCM API - how should I do that?

Comment: The docs page uses an example that most likely uses xmpppy.  You can't just cut and paste it.  I recommend using the HTTP service, it's more straightforward.

Comment: I have thoroughly read the instructions again. I have chosen CCS (XMPP) since it allows upstream and downstream connectivity     (android <- cloud and android -> cloud). Do you have any other suggestions for the tools/architecture I might use for this purpose? All the best,

Comment: You could either use the App Engine XMPP service or try to get xmpppy working - in theory it should be possible with App Engine's outbound socket support.  In both cases you'll have to do some work; there's no cut & paste code.

Comment: But they say CCS cannot be implemented in GAE... so, you suggest abandoning the idea of deploying GCM through Google API, and implementing a native xmpp server instead?

Comment: Or, on the other hand, using GCM, but running the server outside the cloud?

Comment: Well you can run an xmpp server on a cloud provider other than GAE.  You can set one up on Amazon.  Or you could use a service like Urbanairship or Amazons's SNS.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html says
Note that Google AppEngine does not support connections to CCS

Comment: I have probably missed it somehow... Thank you!                                 I have thoroughly read the instructions again. I have chosen CCS (XMPP) since it allows upstream and downstream connectivity     (android <- cloud and android -> cloud). Do you have any other suggestions for the tools/architecture I might use for this purpose? All the best,